# How do i know email sending limit not to be declared as spammer?

Tags: email, smtp, spam

I need to implement in our CRM the mass email sending from our customers to their contacts. I am sorry this might be trivial question, but i maybe dont know what keywords to use to google it, how do i find some official standards for number of allowed emails send per hour, so that our users do not end up blacklisted as spammers? I am talking about cca 50 000 emails that would be sent from one of our clients with bigger contact database than others (but number is growing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no official standards, just best practices (and the link Decado posted is a good resource in that regard). You need to understand that people can block you from sending email to their server for any reason they choose and they can define "Spam" as pretty much anything they like. So there's no certain way to prevent blacklisting from taking place.

Personally, I've always felt that the best thing to do with bulk email campaigns is to outsource them to a *reputable* specialist company, who will not only help you determine best practice but who will also have a vested interest in making sure its enforced and working properly.

Comment: thanx for the advice, but can you tell me what is reputable company? From my point of view, as CRM developer, who should implement the bulk sending strategy, that would mean actually not to implement but to tell to our customers to consult reputable companies for newsletter sending strategies or....? Thank you!

Comment: Neko, have a look at this answer [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/questions/416/recommendations-for-smtp-services-for-massive-mailing/886#886)

Answer (score 1):

Have a read through at [spamhaus.org](http://www.spamhaus.org/faq/answers.lasso?section=Marketing%20FAQs#214) about what their definitions of the right way to send bulk email. Spamhaus are the people who come up with black and white lists so there will be documentation there.